# ScrollTime Not working on timelineDay View

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

Thanks in advance for reading.  Hopefully this isn't a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find a solution here on my own.

I'm trying to use the timelineDay view (Scheduler).  In it, I'd like to show the whole day (midnight to midnight), but the key hours I need to show start at 6am, so I'd like to use the scrollTime option to do this.

On load, it starts at 6am, but after it's done loading it automatically flips back to Midnight. So for a brief moment, I see it correctly load to 6am.  Then,once it's done loading in all the events, it flips back to midnight.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I cannot trace it back to what's causing this to happen or figure out how to set it back to 6am.  Any help would be appreciated.

Also - to note, we haven't paid the Scheduler Plugin fee yet.  I'm about to, but wanted to make sure this works correctly for us before doing so.  Maybe that is why?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    resourceAreaWidth: 230,
    timezone: 'local',
    editable: false,
    slotWidth: 50,
    scrollTime: '06:00',

    ... other content ...
});
```

Video of what's going on:
https://youtu.be/1GzswF90Y1g

Comment: UPDATE:  I did this to hack a fix for now:

    eventAfterAllRender: function(view) { 
        console.log("AFTER ALL RENDER");
        $('.fc-scroller').scrollLeft(600)            
    },

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found a hack; another solution would be to set this:

```
minTime: "06:00"
```

That would mean the part of the calendar before 6am would be entirely inaccessible, but that may be fine for some users.

Answer (score -1):

Scroll Time will not work for day view. I have used a hack like this

```
$('.fc-scroller').scrollLeft($('.fc-start').offset().left);
```

It will scroll to the events start.
Hope it helps